# Invoking a simple worker role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-scheduler

I'm trying to gain some understanding and experience in creating background processes on Azure.

I've created a simple console app and converted it to Azure Worker Role. How do I invoke it? I tried to use Azure Scheduler but looks like the scheduler can only invoke a worker role through message queues or HTTP/HTTPS.

I never thought about any type of communication as my idea was to create a background process that does not really communicate with any other app. Do I need to convert the worker role to a web role and invoke it using Azure Scheduler using HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: Are you talking about a Worker Role or a Web Job.  It sounds to me like you actually want a Web Job.

Comment: I think you're missing a key point about Worker Roles: They are *virtual machines*. They're not a task you simply invoke.

Comment: David, you're right. I wasn't clear about that. What is the solution I'm looking for then? I simply want to call a background task.

Answer (score -1):

Worker role has three events:

1. OnStart
2. OnRun
3. OnStop

> ```
> public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
>   {
>       ManualResetEvent CompletedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
>
>       public override void Run()
>       {
>           //Your background processing code
>           CompletedEvent.WaitOne();
>       }
>
>       public override bool OnStart()
>       {
>           return base.OnStart();
>       }
>
>       public override void OnStop()
>       {
>           CompletedEvent.Set();
>           base.OnStop();
>       }
>   }
> ```

The moment you run/debug your console converted worker role. First two (OnStart & OnRun) fires in sequence. Now in OnRun you have to keep the thread alive, either by using a while loop or using `ManualResetEvent` this is where your background processing code would live.

OnStop is fired when you either release the thread from OnRun or something un-expected goes. This is the place to dispose your objects. Close unclosed file-handles database connection etc.